# Locking all DataTables in DataSet to perform safe Update

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net, locking, dataset

I'm developing an application where i have a single Dataset (it represents an Access DataBase) which has several Datatables in it.
Then i have threads that simultaneously are inserting/editing/deleting rows in the various datatables.

From time to time i have a thread that commits the datatable changes to the DataBase (invoking the update method on every datatable). My problem is that the datatables have some relationships that are being violated. Let me give an example, i have this in the thread that commits the changes to the database:

```
If DS.Tables.Contains("TableA") Then SyncLock DS.Tables("TableA") : TableADataAdapter.Update(DS.Tables("TableA")) : End SyncLock
If DS.Tables.Contains("TableB") Then SyncLock DS.Tables("TableB") : TableBDataAdapter.Update(DS.Tables("TableB")) : End SyncLock
```

TableA is parent of TableB so there is a column with an ID that every record in TableB must have a corresponding value in TableA

Sometimes after TableA is updated a thread inserts a record in TableA and TableB and when i update TableB there is a missing parent record from TableA and a relation is break (an exception is thrown)

I have tried to lock the DataSet to see if all the DataTables inside the DataSet would become locked objects but the exception remains.

```
SyncLock DS: Do The Updates : End SyncLock
```

My question is: Is there any way to Lock all the DataTables simultaneously so i can update the database safely?

Thanks for any advises

Comment: Is the code that actually makes the changes to the `DataSet` also in the same kind of `SyncLock` block?

Comment: Thanks steven.
Yes, whenever i Insert/Update/Delete a row in a datatable i will always do:
    SyncLock DS.Tables("TableA") : Insert/Update/Delete : End SyncLock

Comment: When you changed it to `SyncLock DS`, did you also change those places to `DS` as well?

Comment: No, i didn't wanted to always lock the entire DataSet on every Datatable change, i just wanted that whole lock when the update was being done.

Comment: `SyncLock` does not work like that.  Calling `SyncLock` doesn't lock the object that you give it.  Rather, `SyncLock` blocks the enclosed code so it doesn't execute at the same time as any other code `SyncLock`'ing on the same object.  Therefore, you need to SyncLock on `DS` everywhere, or you need to look into more advanced synchronization techniques such as `AutoResetEvent`, `WaitHandle` etc.  Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with those so I'm not the best one to help you further.

Comment: Thanks Steven, i get it, SyncLock doesn't lock the object itself, just locks pieces of code inside the same SyncLock Object. I think there must be a better solution than locking the same object whenever i do a change on one DataTable. Whenever i change DataTable A i shouldnt have to lock DataTable B (that would hurt performance).
I wanted to use the "global dataset lock" only when updating.

Answer (score 3):

So, the final solution is locking individual objects for each DataTable and then locking them all when i want to update:

While modifying rows in the different threads:

```
SyncLock DataTableALock
    Insert/Edit/Delete Rows
End SyncLock

SyncLock DataTableBLock
    Insert/Edit/Delete Rows
End SyncLock
```

When i want to commit the changes:

```
SyncLock DataTableALock
    SyncLock DataTableBLock
        Commit Changes
    End SyncLock
End SyncLock
```

I think this code is safe and doesn't lock the dataset as a whole every time i want to change a row (just the individual DataTables). It's just ugly but i can live with that.

Comment: That will definitely work.  It's ugly, but it is nice and simple.  I'm a believer in sticking with what you understand.  It's dangerous to dabble in technologies that you don't fully grasp.  So, this sounds like the best solution for you for the moment.  But, if you are going to be working with multi-threading often, I would recommend investing some time in seriously trying to learn more about the more advanced synchronization techniques.  +1, though for a working simple solution.

Comment: Thanks @Steven Doggart for pointing that out. I will maintain this solution and eventually use this problem to learn about the other synchronization techniques that seem more adaptable to "complex situations".

Answer (score 0):

To summarize i need to update all my DataTables while i know the relationships are being respected and for that i need to stop/halt any changes to the DataTables during this process.

One possible solution for this problem, but a poor one and with a lot of potential to go wrong, is to put a Public Flag that signalizes the update and then checking for that flag value in every place that i make a datatable change. Something like this:

```
If UpdateIsRunnig = True Then 
   Do While UpdateIsRunnig = True : Loop
End If
Insert/Edit/Delete Rows in Datatable
```

This is very dangerous and it doesn't assure me that a change will not occur while im committing the changes to the back end database. 
So this is a poor and partial solution.
I will try to figure it out if there's a better way of doing this.
Any help is much appreciated.

Edit:
As PHeiberg pointed out, the only truly current solution that i have is to have a Global SyncLock object that i use in every change that i make on the DataSet then use it in the Update. Like this:

```
SyncLock GlobalDataSetLock
    Insert/Edit/Delete Rows
End SyncLock
```

And on the Update:

```
SyncLock GlobalDataSetLock
    Commit Changes to DataBase using "Update"
End SyncLock
```

This is a solution, it really solves the problem, but the performance issues are huge. As i said in a comment i really don't need to Lock DataTable A to make changes in DataTable B so locking the whole DataSet just to do the Update later is really frustrating.

Comment: Ouch! That is a terrible "solution" that does more harm than good. Replace the flag with the Monitor/SyncLock from your question instead and ditch the tight loop.

Comment: thanks @PHeiberg for pointing that out, i made an edit on the proposed answer.